# What is the purpose of the HTML <data> tag

Tags: javascript, html

What is the purpose of the HTML <data> tag?  Does anybody use this tag?

How does it differ from the data-* attributes used in other tag elements?

Documentation indicates it is for machine-readable information.  What machine?

Is there an example of how the HTML tag <data value='12345'> Jumbo Shrimp </data> would be used with javascript?
(Reference example at: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_data.asp)

Comment: I reckon it's more "standard" than `data-some-made-up-attribute` so it'll be easier for apps to find & parse if needed. MDN doesn't really say much more either; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/data

Comment: The specs are actually quite explanatory on the intended uses of this tag: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-data-element "machine-readable" means any script, not necessarily JS, this can go from site scrappers to internal scripts that could read the page sources directly. For use by JS in the page the `data-` attribute can indeed be used equivalently.